# Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
const notes = [{},{
    title: 'Learn to code',
    body: 'I would like to be good at javascript'
}, {
    title: 'Build Muscle',
    body: 'Exercise. Eating better'
}, {
    title: 'Gaming PC',
    body: 'Build the new parts of my pc'
}]

    const filters = {
        searchText: ''
    }

    const renderNotes = function (notes, filters){
        const filteredNotes = notes.filter(function(note){
            return note.title.toLowerCase().includes(filters.searchText.toLowerCase())
        })
        console.log(filteredNotes);
        
    }

    renderNotes(notes, filters)

    document.querySelector('#create-note').addEventListener('click', function(e){
        e.target.textContent = 'The button was clicked'
        
    })

   document.querySelector('#remove-all').addEventListener('click', function(){
        document.querySelectorAll('.note').forEach(function( note){
                note.remove()
        })
        
   })

   document.querySelector('#search-text').addEventListener('input', function(e){
       filters.searchText = e.target.value
       renderNotes(notes, filters)
   })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>notes</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Notes app</h1>
    <h2>Take notes and never forget</h2>
    <input id="search-text" type="text" placeholder="Enter">
    <p class="note">App was made by Mani</p>
    <p class="note">KFC is peng</p>
    <button id="create-note">Click Here</button>
    <button id="remove-all">Remove All Notes</button>
    <script src="notes-app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I cant seem to find the issue, im sure i havent misspelt anything. I have made sure my brackets are placed correctly and that everything in the function is typed correctly. I am a beginner so sorry if its a basic issue - Can someone help please ?

Comment: You have an empty object in the first position in your notes array: `const notes = [{},...`. There is no `title` property on that object

Comment: `[{}` <-- because of that, it has no title

Comment: your `notes` array has an object that doesn't have a `title` property.

Comment: Your first object is empty in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the first empty object you have on the code

```
const notes = [{},{
```

```
const notes = [{
```